# Chrome Extension error: "The Content Security Policy directive 'sandbox' is ignored when delivered in a report-only policy."

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

In testing a chrome extension that I am developing, I occasionally get the following error: "The Content Security Policy directive 'sandbox' is ignored when delivered in a report-only policy."

The stack trace states "js/jquery.js:5 (anonymous function)"

I cannot find any literature on this particular error. Is it showing just because this is an unpacked extension or is there something more serious going on that I will have to solve before publishing it?

FWIW, the extension has no apparent errors when using it. These errors occasionally get logged while in use, but I have seen no problems on the front end.

Comment: it tried when I posted, buit 84000 characters and exceeded the limits for SO. Line 5 is over 40,000 as it is.

Comment: Though the code is too long to post, the latest jquery.js is viewable here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js. I've updated the extension with this script, and the error code remains. It now say "js/jquery.js:2" for the stack trace.

Comment: What does the :5 mean?  Can you share details about the anonymous function?  Can you put a console.log statement in this function to reveal what line(s) of code might be the issue?

Comment: the :5 just means it's the 5th line of code in the jquery. But the compact jquery file is humongous and can't be pasted here. I linked to it instead.

Answer (score 1):

> The Content Security Policy directive 'sandbox' is ignored when delivered in a report-only policy

means that you (or third-party iframe) publish [Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only](http://csplite.com/csp69/#content-security-policy-report-only) HTTP header with the `sandbox` directive. This is just warning that this directive is not work in `-Report-Only` mode, it's work only in enforced mode (`Content-Security-Policy`).

`jquery.js` has nothing to do with it.